# How to maintain a single code base on a multi server node app

Tags: node.js, git, architecture, system

I have multiple servers on a load balanced environment running the same Node application. I want the code on these servers be the same everywhere. I currently maintain a git repo for the code on these servers but have to manually SSH into each of these and pull the code from the git repo. Is there any simple way I can push the code onto all the servers?

Comment: if you found any of the answer below useful, please consider to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straightforward solutions that came in my mind:

1) use a `cron` job on the servers that makes the work you're doing manually, i.e., git pull (need linux), or

2) use `git hooks` to trigger the pull on the other servers. With this solution you need to have the list of servers to trigger the update. Hooks are basically scripts that are executed before/after events like commits, push, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It looks your question is how to deploy Node.js app into multiple server.  Here [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20043913/how-to-simultaneously-deploy-node-js-web-app-on-multiple-servers-with-jenkins)